# Problems compiling rJava with RStudio on macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: r, clang, macos-sierra, rjava

I am trying to install the rJava package into Rstudio using these instructions:

[https://github.com/MTFA/CohortEx/wiki/Run-rJava-with-RStudio-under-OSX-10.10,-10.11-(El-Capitan)-or-10.12-(Sierra)](http://gitHub_tutorial)

However, when I run this command:

```
unset JAVA_HOME R --quiet -e 'install.packages("rJava", type="source", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")'
```

I am getting this error:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
```

Any workarounds or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here. Lots depends on R version. It might be that you need to recompile rJava

[R 3.4, rJava, macOS and even more mess ;)](http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3718)

[R, Java, rJava and macOS adventures](http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3671)

You need compiler with OpenMP support - thus, you need to use different clang version comparing to what you get out of the box.